# Bash script to loop through folders and list files to text

Tags: bash, shell-script

I can do this in Windows CMD scripting but now I am getting into Debian via Raspberry Pi.

What I'd like to do is...

(In current folder)

- For each subfolder...

  - Create a file called original_filenames.txt
  - Echo the name of the folder into this original_filenames.txt
  - List all files (including any subfolders) to original_filenames.txt

Comment: What are you having an issue doing? Please include the script you are attempting to use in your question and any errors you are encountering.

Comment: Do you want to descend into subfolders and list those files?

Comment: Yes I want to recurse through subfolders. I think I've got something working now, I was getting an error until I added quotes to deal with spaces in folder names:`#!/bin/bash; 
for dir in */ ; do ; tree -s "$dir">"$dir/original_filenames.txt"; done`

Comment: That's a good lesson. You'll want to read [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/4667)

Answer (score 2):

Using a shell loop:

```
for dir in */; do
    { printf '%s\n' "$dir"
      ( cd "$dir" && find . )
    } >"$dir/original_filenames.txt"
done
```

This iterates over all subdirectories in the current directory.  The body of the loop outputs the name of the directory, and then a list of all files and directories, recursively, in that directory.  This output goes to the `original_filenames.txt` file in the directory.

Shorter:

```
for dir in */; do
    find "$dir" >"$dir/original_filenames.txt"
done
```

This gives slightly different output in that the pathnames that are written to the file all start with the name of the subfolder.

If you're uninterested in directory names and just want pathnames of the regular files, use `find` with `-type f` after the directory name.

---

Note that if you're planning on *using* the generate output files for anything, then this will fail (or at least be very problematic) if any of the found pathnames contain newlines (which is entirely possible on a Unix system).

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with the `find` command and the `exec` option - something like this:

```bsh
find . -type d \( ! -name . \) -exec bash -c '
    dirname=$(basename "{}") && 
    cd "{}" && 
    echo "{}" > original_filenames.txt && 
    ls | grep -Fv original_filenames.txt >> original_filenames.txt
' \;
```

Here's a StackOverflow post you might find useful:

- [How to go to each directory and execute a command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7470165/how-to-go-to-each-directory-and-execute-a-command)

Comment: For readability, you can have newlines in a single quoted string, and `&&` at the *end* of a line does not require a line continuation.

Comment: Instead of putting `{}` in the middle of the shell script, you may want to pass it as an argument and use `"$1"` inside the shell script, to avoid issues with strange filenames. Also, I can't see what `dirname` is used for here, and you don't need `\( \)` around `! -name .`.

Comment: @ilkkachu Thanks for the comment. The unused `dirname` was a typo/mistake on my part. I'm now using it to add just the filename to the output file. The `! -name . `  was to ignore the current directory (i.e. to only apply the commands to proper subdirectories) - I removed it.

Comment: @glennjackman Thanks for the comment. I've update my post as you suggested.

Comment: @igal, I added a version I think is readable. If you don't like, please edit it out.